# Trace was cut during a modification of synthesizer, how to repair

Tags: trace, synthesizer

I received a Roland TB303 synth that has issues. When I opened it to see what the issue was, to my horror I found that a prior owner had seemingly cut a trace intentionally.

[image]

How are these fixed? Is there any way to fix this by some kind of copper deposition electroplating? The cut is too thin to solder the very thin trace. I don't want to apply heat.

Comment: Why don't you want to apply heat? Simply solder between the two joints. It's also a good opportunity to fix the bad joint at the top end of the resistor.

Comment: Yeah, you can fix it, you solder the bridge together with a wire or solder. It looks like the resistor is soldered on also so you'll have to look at the schematic and decide why they did that

Comment: you can't easily make it look like new. but a good electrical connection is all that's needed for it to work the same.

Comment: I'd solder a jumper wire between the two pins that are supposed to be joined by that trace...and remove the resistor that they soldered in (probably when they cut the trace). That resistor is *definitely* "aftermarket." - Also, check **very carefully** for any other modifications a previous owner may have made to the board...looks like somebody was having "amateur EE night" on that poor thing!

Comment: You need to do some research on what this is doing, it could even be a genuine manufacturing fix

Comment: ^ Exactly. Unless you know exactly what that does, and why it was done, it doesn't really make sense to "fix" it. Is it actually broken? "If it ain't broke..."

Answer (score 5):

Beware. If it looks like a trace was cut intentionally, then maybe that trace was cut intentionally. If you simply restore that trace, you may be undoing a *bona fide* modification, with consequences ranging from nothing significant to burning out some vital parts.

You'll notice there's an extra resistor soldered on to the node next to the track cut. This is a very common way to modify a board from its original design, cut a track and add a new component, a scalpel is part of the standard tool-kit of a development engineer. Often a product will start to ship before the design is fully finished, and this is done to correct a late-surfacing defect. Or a key part has gone obsolete, and a repair with a similar but not identical part requires a modification somewhere else.

First, get the serial number of that unit. Then go to the manufacturer's documentation, and see whether there are any recommended modifications to boards used in that serial number. You may have to look on more specialist forums dedicated to this sort of gear to point you in the right direction.

Comment: desoldering that resistor and restoring the cut trace isn't hard, but you really should try to find out why the trace was cut and the resistor installed where it was to begin with.  what does the schematic look like with the trace connected or with it cut and with or without the resistor?

Comment: I have since had pre-eminent Roland experts look at this and this is apparently not a modification but a very early revision of the TB-303.

Answer (score 0):

Without applying heat? No such thing.

Scrape away some solder resist with a knife, wet the surfaces with some leaded tinn and bridge it with a piece of resistor leg, just like the mod but without the conponent body.

Comment: What? You've never heard of conductive (metal-filled) epoxy?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sounds suspicious. Call me old-fashioned but when my old electronics starts to squeek (or stops it it was supposed to), I reach out for some good old solder. Gets the job done every time.